# Why is LocationManager not being called in iOS Simulator, but it's being called on the phone?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

```
//in my viewDidLoad()
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    self.locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied{
        println("location not authorized")
    }


//somewhere down the file

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    println("Location") //this prints on the phone, not simulator
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

I also have "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" in the plist.

[image]

Comment: Check this link [http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/](http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/). Might be helpful

Comment: Probably because there are no location updates, it's just a single location that doesn't change. Try to go to Simulator: Debug - Location - and select some of the 3 last options, they generate location updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just reset your Simulator from here:

[image]

Hope It helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's an iOS 8 related issue. You have to put `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` or `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` keys in your .plist file (value may be an additional message that will be presented in location alert). These keys are required in iOS 8.

How it's said in Apple guidelines:

I ended up solving my own problem.

Apparently in iOS 8 SDK, `requestAlwaysAuthorization` (for background location) or `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` (location only when foreground) call on `CLLocationManager` is needed before starting location updates.

There also needs to be `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` or `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key in Info.plist with a message to be displayed in the prompt. Adding these solved my problem.

```
self.locationManager.delegate = self
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
self.locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a bug in iOS8 beta5 which always deactivate geolocation service for your app (at least for mine).

Go in settings > Privacy > Location services > Your app > Always.

But I don't know why, but even if you set it to Always this setting will auto-deactivate, so please be patient and often return in the settings to configure again your app location.

Answer (score 0):

On first time simulator launch not initialise location even by setting from 
Debug->Location->Custom Location from ios8. So you need to first select none option from debug->Location->None like following

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAl14.png

and then next you should following

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCtfB.png
```

now finally you should run again your application on simulator and by using 
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key in your plist you should use following code:

```
locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

Answer (score -2):

Simulator doesn't have GPS enabled in it. So for location base things we should use Device. Simulator will always give you a location (0,0) by default.